# how to submit form on button click

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, forms

I have a form in which i have two buttons one is `save` and other is `save as draft` , so on save i am submiting the form to other `servlet` and on `save as Draft` click i want to give action to new servlet class

- I am doing `<button type="submit" id="saveDraft" formaction="InsertAsDraft"">`,but its not working

```html
<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form action="InsertQuantityIndent" method="post" id="indentForm" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="row position-relative">
      <div class="col-lg-4  brder">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Outlet Name</h5>
        <select class="test" id="outlet" name="outlet">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>ol1</option>
          <option>ol2</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Category</h5>
        <select class="test" id="CategoryName" name="categoryCode">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>Cat1</option>
          <option>Cat2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div>
      <button type="submit" id="save" class="commonButton">
        <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
       </button>
      <button type="submit" id="saveDraft" formaction="InsertAsDraft" class="commonButton">
        <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save as draft
       </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

when i click on save the form gets submitted to `InsertQuantityIndent`, but when i click on `save as draft` it gets submitted but no data gets to back end

Like `request.getparameter` in servlet

Here is my servlet

```
    String outlet = request.getParameter("outlet");
    String CategoryCode= request.getParameter("categoryCode");
   System.out.println("outlet in new file :"+outlet);
```

here it print nothing, so i want to submit form on button click and get that data to back end bye its name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you can name buttons and check which value for button came and process accordingly.

```
<button type="submit" id="save" name="btn_save" class="commonButton">
   <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
 </button>
 <button type="submit" id="saveDraft" name="btn_save_draft" class="commonButton">
   <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save as draft
 </button>
```

or you can change type of button to button and handle click listener. From your listener change your form action and submit it using javascript.

Comment: For saving use this **InsertQuantityIndent** and for draft use **InsertAsDraft**

use this for setting action 
document.getElementById("indentForm").setAttribute("action", "indentForm");

Comment: yupp on first click and on secon button also

Comment: have you got my problem..my issue is to submit a form to two different paths

Comment: check it out first. On save it will be posted to **InsertQuantityIndent** and on save draft to **InsertAsDraft**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187574/discussion-between-manj1790-and-dheeraj-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container" id="divHide">
   <form action="InsertQuantityIndent" method="post" id="indentForm" autocomplete="on">
      <div class="row position-relative">
         <div class="col-lg-4  brder">
            <h5 id="commonHeader">Outlet Name</h5>
            <select class="test" id="outlet" name="outlet">
               <option>All</option>
               <option>ol1</option>
               <option>ol2</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h5 id="commonHeader">Category</h5>
            <select class="test" id="CategoryName" name="categoryCode">
               <option>All</option>
               <option>Cat1</option>
               <option>Cat2</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
      <div>
         <button id="save" class="commonButton" data-formAction="servlet">
         <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
         </button>
         <button id="saveDraft" data-formAction="InsertAsDraft" class="commonButton">
         <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save as draft
         </button>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
const formElm = document.getElementById('indentForm');

const saveButton = document.getElementById("save");
saveButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let elm = e.target;
  const formAction = elm.dataset.formaction;
  console.log(formAction);

  formElm.action = formAction;

  formElm.submit();
});

const saveDraftButton = document.getElementById("saveDraft");
saveDraftButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let elm = e.target;
  const formAction = elm.dataset.formaction;
  console.log(formAction);

  formElm.action = formAction;

  formElm.submit();
});
```

You can find the working example stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qmsnzc

Comment: hey will the values i am calling at my servlet via `request.getParameter` will it print the data? or can you explain me  how it will work

Comment: Actually, I never worked with Java but the above code will work

Comment: as i am using get post which is user in almost all languages to get values from client as name

Comment: `POST` method is used to send data to backend

Comment: same i want to do here

Comment: as off your code i am getting error here `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large`